# Novel about a chemist killed by alien spacecraft then revived

Tags: story-identification, aliens, soft-sci-fi, alien-abduction

I'm trying to find out the author and title of a book that was published some time after 2000 , possibly by Baen.

A chemist is on a spaceship whose mission is to observe but not interfere. He is accidentally "killed" in a midair collision with an alien spacecraft. He is given a choice: die, or be relocated to another world occupied by humans living with approximately 19th century technology.

He is modified via nano or biotechnology which enhanced his healing and was transmitted to his intimate partners and children giving them improved wound healing. His knowledge of chemistry and other science topics sparked a industrial revolution in his new home. This attracted the attention of the local ruler whose nation's survival is threatened by the imperial ambitions of one of its neighbors.

The book is not Edmund Cooper's *Seahorse in the Sky* (1969).

I quite enjoyed the book and hope to read a sequel if it exists.

Comment: Please add a bit more detail to your question - [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/70236) is a good place to start.

Comment: The ship is on a mission to observe and not interfere. The chemist is given the choice: die or be relocated to another world occupied by humans living with approximately 19th century technology.

Comment: Any chance this might be Edmund Cooper's "Seahorse in the Sky" (1969)? Details don't line up precisely, but if you allow for some memory erosion, it's not a bad match.

Comment: That's not it. I'm fairly certain the book I'm looking for was published in the post 2000 period, possibly by Baen. The chemist was modified via nano or biotechnology which enhanced his healing and were transmitted to his intimate partners and children giving them improved wound healing. His knowledge of chemistry and other science topics sparked a industrial revolution which attracted the attention of the local ruler whose nation's survival  is threatened by one of its neighbors imperial ambitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Cast Under an Alien Sun](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30985483-cast-under-an-alien-sun)* (Destiny's Crucible Book 1) by Olan Thorensen

[image: Book Cover - Cast Under an Alien Sun]

> Joe Colsco boarded a flight from San Francisco to Chicago to attend a national chemistry meeting. He would never set foot on Earth again.
>
> On planet Anyar, Joe is found unconscious on a beach of a large island inhabited by humans where the level of technology is similar to Earth circa 1700. He awakes amidst strangers speaking an unintelligible language, and struggles to accept losing his previous life and finding a place in a society with different customs, needing a way to support himself, and not knowing a single soul. His worry about finding a place is assuaged when he finds ways to apply his knowledge of chemistry—as long as he is circumspect in introducing new knowledge not too far in advance of the planet’s technology and being labelled a demon.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Can you edit your answer to mention some of the elements of this book which match OP's criteria? Also, we recommend that new users take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).